# How can I solve the recursion tree T(n)=2T(n/2)+2/log(n)

Tags: recursion

I would like to get some help I just don't know how to finish the sum :

I got:

$$T(n)=2^{k}T(\dfrac{n}{2^k}) + \sum_{i=1}^{log_{2}n} \dfrac{2^{i}}{log(\frac{n}{2^{i-1}})}$$

when $k=log_2n$  I get:

$$n+\sum_{i=1}^{log_2n}  \dfrac{2^i}{log(\frac{n}{2^{i-1}})}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can you do it when $n$ is a power of $2$?  That must be the easy case.

Comment: I think that this is o.k.

Comment: CAS says:$\sum _{i=1}^{\log _2(n)} \frac{2^i}{\log \left(\frac{n}{2^{i-1}}\right)}=\frac{2 \left(\Phi \left(2,1,\log _2(n)\right)-n \Phi \left(2,1,2
   \log _2(n)\right)\right)}{\log (2)}$ where :$\Phi$ is [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html)